# How do you trigger vistas?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am in the Grove, right by a map marker for an "undiscovered vista." There seems to be nothing special about it except for a nearby balcony. There seems to be no apparent trigger around except for a discussion tree with Nikkyta (which apparently I've known since forever except I'm not even born yet, but that's a matter for a different day.)

[image]

So... what am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vistas are often in hard to reach places above the ground, most likely on a roof or on top of a stone formation. To reach it, there should be a more or less obvious path leading to this place, often requiring a few jumps.

The specific marker to trigger a vista is a small light shaft with a vista icon floating above. You just need to be in the light and press F in order to trigger it. The hard part is both locating and reaching the vista itself.

In this specific example, the answer is directly in front of your eyes:

[image: Climb those stairs!]

Comment: +1. The floating map with a beam of light [looks like this](http://oyster.ignimgs.com/mediawiki/apis.ign.com/guild-wars-2/thumb/a/a8/Gw2vista.jpg/468px-Gw2vista.jpg)

Comment: Note also the small up arrow next to the vista symbol on your mini-map - this indicates the vista is above your current location

Comment: @Gwen I only noticed this recently as well and is very useful. It also shows up on skill point markers and (probably) a few other map icons

Comment: PoI's and waypoints, harvesting nodes too!